# What is mean of "specific point" that He/She said by comment

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my English Language Learners Stack Exchange post: [What is all grammar wrong in the question(page)?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130146/what-is-all-grammar-wrong-in-the-questionpage)

A [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130146/what-is-all-grammar-wrong-in-the-questionpage#comment261886_130146) I can't understand He/She said "specific point",due I "still can't what's wrong with it"(as He/She said).

So what is mean of His/Her comment?

He/She meaning is advised me post a shorter question then post a question for short article?

Comment: This site is not for correcting someone's writing (proof reading). A "specific point" means to ask something about English, and not to ask for someone to find all the mistakes and fix them. For example, you could ask *Is 'vs' the correct word to use in 'This site vs report bug?'* instead of *What is wrong in 'This site vs report bug?' Here are a few examples of questions with a specific point: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/80700/ https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/120953/ https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/112716/